# aws_sdk__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.StepFunctions is not a constructor

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I have integrated AWS SDK in my angular app. I imported the AWS library using:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

I initialised the step functions using:

```
var stepFunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();
```

Compiler throws an error `aws_sdk__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.StepFunctions is not a constructor`

Answer (score 3):

Import the stepfunctions specifically to solve this issue:

```
import * as StepFunctions from "aws-sdk/clients/stepfunctions";

or 

const StepFunctions = require('aws-sdk/clients/stepfunctions');
```

Comment: thanx for your answer.